# Error at Line : syntax error near ORDER in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I was trying to get some data from an AccessDB file using MDBTools in PHP.
All the normal SQL queries are working except ORDER BY and GROUP BY

When I use ORDER BY I am getting error

> Error at Line : syntax error near ORDER
>   syntax error near ORDER
>   Got no result for 'SELECT * FROM CHECKINOUT ORDER BY CHECKTIME DESC' command

This is the code

```
$dataSourceName = "odbc:Driver=$driver;DBQ=$mdb_file;";
$conn = new PDO($dataSourceName);
$q = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM CHECKINOUT ORDER BY CHECKTIME DESC");
$q->execute();
$result = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
print_r($result);
```

[Update]
When i used the above query in mysqli, it worked like charm. I created the database similar to the database on the access db file and used this code,

```
$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
$row = $conn->query("SELECT USERID, CHECKTIME, CHECKTYPE FROM CHECKINOUT ORDER BY USERID DESC");
$result = $row->fetch_object();
print_r($result);
```

The above code worked like charm.
But not when using PDO.

Comment: Is there a `CHECKTIME` column?

Comment: That is what I'm wondering.

Comment: Your query looks right

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yes. There is a column named `CHECKTIME`

Comment: @JayBlanchard, @unixmiah When I removed the `ORDER BY CHECKTIME` the query executed successfully.

Comment: Is `CHECKINOUT` a regular table or is it a view?

Comment: @aynber It is a regular Table.

Comment: You possibly have a non-printable character. You can use any hexadecimal editor to confirm that.

Comment: I'm confused. Is `$mdb_file` related to MySQL?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález when I use just `SELECT * FROM CHECKINOUT' I get all the data from the table. But when `ORDER BY' was added the above error is displayed. And `ORDER BY' is not working on any table when using PDO. But works when using mysqli

Comment: I confess I find it kind of distressing when I leave a comment with a specific suggestion and all I get back is another copy of the question.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I'm Sorry. What I meant was I have printed the whole table using the Select command and there was no error as about non-printable character the whole table was printed successfully. But when used 'ORDER BY' things went wrong.

Comment: I guess you don't have an hexadecimal editor. You can upload your source code to [HexEd.it](https://hexed.it/). Find the part where `SELECT * FROM CHECKINOUT ORDER BY CHECKTIME DESC` is written and make sure there aren't more characters than the ones you expect. I'm not claiming this is the problem but it's a sensible path to research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First does the query work without ORDER BY?

On the local linux box i use connecting to an .MDB, I cannot use ORDER BY at all.
Im not sure if this is due to the odbc drivers, or a configuration error somewhere on my end. Im pretty sure GROUP BY and ORDER BY just aren't supported. However i cant point you to documentation.

```
    $conn = new PDO("odbc:Driver=MDBTools; DBQ=$mdb_file; UID=; PWD=;");
    $q = $conn->prepare("SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM some_table WHERE FINISHED = 0");
    $success = $q->execute();
    $error_info = $q->errorInfo(); // if needed

    $result = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    aasort($rows, "col2");
```

I would suggest getting the rows then sorting afterwards.
It isn't what your asking but it accomplishes the same thing (or should)

EDIT: sorry i forgot to include aasort, i thought the function was built in.

```
function aasort (&$array, $key) {
    $sorter = [];
    $toreturn = [];
    reset($array);

    foreach ($array as $ii => $va)
        $sorter[$ii] = $va[$key];

    arsort($sorter);

    foreach ($sorter as $ii => $va)
        $toreturn[$ii] = $array[$ii];

    $array = $toreturn;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the above code suggestion. I will give that a try. And the code is working without using ORDER BY.

Comment: In Microsoft Access, both [ORDER BY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208913%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [GROUP BY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177905(v=office.12).aspxhttps://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177905(v=office.12).aspx) exist. Of course, ODBC drivers are a world themselves. But I don't know if he's using Access or MySQL Server (I'm not sure the OP knows either).